# D3 error while trying to label H axis using tickValue

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a object as such

```
bardata={
  0:{
   value:10
   label:A
  }
  1:{
   value:15
   label:B
  }
  2:{
   value:13
   label:C
  }
      3:{

   value:14
   label:D
  } 

}
```

Now I use this data to build a graph where y axis is a linear scale with *data.value* as the parameter , the graph turns out well but for one thing, I can't seem to use *data.label* for the x axis
here is what I get[image]

NOTE:The above data is not my actual data

The way I am trying to label the y axis is :

```
    var hAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom')
        .tickValues( function(){   //this is where the error comes from,it doesn't like the array I feed it
                        var labelArray=[] 
                        bardata.forEach(function(d){
                        labelArray.push(String(d.label))
                        })
                    console.log('labelArray ',labelArray);//it is array of strings      
                    return labelArray;

                    });

     var hGuide=d3.select('svg').append('g') ;
      hAxis(hGuide);
      hGuide.attr('transform','translate('+margin.left+','+(height+margin.top)+')');//Here is where I translate the ticks
      var path =hGuide.selectAll('path')
    console.log(path); 
    hGuide.selectAll('path')
        .style({ fill: 'none', stroke: "#000"})
    hGuide.selectAll('line')
        .style({ stroke: "#000"})
}
```

I get console error as :

```
Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(NaN,0)"
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Where is the error coming from? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have edited the question to say where the error comes from,it basically doesn't like the array i.e. labelArray I feed tickValue()

Comment: You're not showing us any code that sets a `transform` attribute. You're also not using `.tickValues()` correctly; see the [API documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues).

Comment: the transform attribute error I believe comes form d3 source code. 

Also read the documentation, but don't understand how I am using tickValues() wrongly . I do pass an array to it

Comment: You're passing a function to `.tickValues()`. What tells you that the error comes from where you think it comes from?

Comment: the function returns an array so I am passing an array,

when I pass a numerical array it works ,thats why  I think thats where the error is coming from

Comment: You're passing a function. Passing a function that returns an array is not the same as passing an array. Try populating the array separately and then pass the array (not the function) to `.tickValues()`.

Comment: I did try that , but it gives me the same error, I also tried passing a hard coded array ['A','B','C','D'] still the same error

Comment: Can you show us your complete code please? How is the scale set up?

Comment: Here is the entire code on fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ay747evy/2/

it might not work  because of the CORS error,  and also the indentation is little messy

Comment: You're defining your x scale to take numbers as input, so you have to provide numbers for the tick values.

Comment: Doesn't .xScale = d3.scale.ordinal() make it to accept categorical values?I am confused here

Comment: You are defining the domain to take numbers. Please have a close look at your code and make sure that you understand what it does.